# log4j2 - IfAccumulatedFileSize property doesn't work

Tags: log4j2

I use log4j 2 for logging in me application.

I have 3 requirements:

- logs files should consume not more then some amount of disk space - for example 800KB
- size of each logs files should be less then some amount - for example 100KB
- name of each log file should have date in it

Sometimes there would be a lot of logs during the day, sometimes there would be no logs during the day.

So this is example of what I want to see on date 13 september 2022:

- test.log - 0KB
- test-2022-09-12-1.log - 50KB
- test-2022-09-10-1.log - 50KB
- test-2022-09-09-1.log - 50KB
- test-2022-09-09-2.log - 100KB
- test-2022-09-08-1.log - 75KB
- test-2022-09-08-2.log - 100KB
- test-2022-09-08-3.log - 100KB
- test-2022-09-08-4.log - 100KB
- test-2022-09-08-5.log - 100KB
- test-2022-09-07-1.log - 75KB

so together it takes 800KB. And when test.log became no empty, file test-2022-09-07-1.log would be deleted.

I use this configuration:

```
- name: ErrorLoggerAppender
  append: true
  filename: '${log-path}/test.log'
  filePattern: '${log-path}/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log'
  PatternLayout:
    Pattern: 'ERROR    >>> %l %n%d{ISO8601} [%m] %n'
  Policies:
    SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
      size: 100KB
    TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
      interval: 1
      modulate: true
  DefaultRolloverStrategy:
    max: 20
    Delete:
      basePath: '${log-path}/'
      IfFileName:
        glob: '*/*.log'
        IfAccumulatedFileSize:
          exceeds: 800KB
  Filters:
    - LevelRangeFilter:
        minLevel: ERROR
        maxLevel: ERROR
        onMatch: ACCEPT
```

But IfAccumulatedFileSize property doesn't work. 20 log files appear in the directory - each with size of 100KB. And If I remove "max: 20" there would be 7 files because 7 is default.

Is there are something wrong in my configuration? How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Try with `glob: *.log`, since you don't have subfolders under `${log-path}`.

Comment: Tanks, you are right!